# Tensorflow: Reshape and swap elements from tensor(shape=[batchsize]) in a tensor(shape=[batchsize, 2]) with specific order

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, swap

I have a tensor (shape=[batchsize]). I want to reshape the tensor in a specific order and into shape=[-1,2]. I want to have that specific order:

1. Element at [0,0]
2. Element at [1,1]
3. Element at [0,1]
4. Element at [1,0]
5. Element at [2,0]
6. Element at [3,1]
7. Element at [2,1]
8. Element at [3,0] and so on for an unknow batchsize.

Here is an example code with a tensor range=(0 to input=8).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batchsize = tf.placeholder(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.range(0, batchsize, 1) 
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[2, -1])
y = tf.transpose(x)
z = tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1, 2])

input = 8
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    msg = sess.run([z], feed_dict={batchsize: input})
    print(msg)
```

Now my output is:

```
[array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7]], dtype=int32)]
```

But I want the output to be:

```
[array([[0, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 5]], dtype=int32)]
```

**In general**: The important thing is that, looking only at the transformation of a 4x1 block to a 2x2 block, the first 2 elements of the input tensor are on one diagonal and the remaining 2 elements on the counter diagonal.

Keep in mind I do not know how big batchsize is, I just set *input=8* for exemplary reason. In my real code the tensor ´x´ is no range array but complex random numbers, so you cannot sort in any way w.r.t. the values. I just made this code for a demonstration purpose.

This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899488/tensorflow-python-reshape-input-batchsize-to-tensor-batchsize-2-with-speci) but with different order or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212205/swap-tensor-axes-in-tensorflow), after doing the normal reshape with transpose just to swap elements every 2nd row.